# Django models triggers the wrong Signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals

My signals of some custom models somehow is triggered when saving for example the Auth user

This is in my signals.py:

```
product_document_model = 'document_manager.models.ProductDocument'
app_label, _, class_name  = product_document_model.split('.')
product_document_model = get_model(app_label, class_name)

@receiver(post_save, sender=product_document_model)
def save_products(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
   ...
```

My model:

```
import os.path
from django.db import models
class Document(models.Model):
    _file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def file_name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self._file.name)

class ProductDocument(models.Model):
    _file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/products/%Y/%m/%d")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def file_name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self._file.name)
```

Why would the Auth users be triggering this?

Comment: Could you like your model? There's probably something going on with a linked `User` model.

Comment: check it out, added to my questioin

Comment: That would be the wrong model. You're after the `ProductDocument` model according to your signals.py

Comment: oops, fixed it, even changing the Sites model in admin triggers this signal

Comment: Do you have any sending signals that you might confuse it with? Also, what happens when you do this `@reciever(post_save, sender=ProductDocument)`

Comment: Ok, this worked, except with the model Document. Changing the name to someelse like CSVDocument made it work... weird!!?

Comment: It's probably something else entirely but it's hard to pinpoint without seeing all of your code. Now you know what might cause it anyways :)